# Use C++ DLLs from the same VS compiled at different times/teams - ABI compatibility?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, abi, visual-c++-2015

**To repeat: I'm looking for ABI compatibility between libraries of *the same* Visual-C++ version!**

We want to mix and match some internal C++ DLLs from different teams - built at different times with different project files. Because of long build times, we exactly want to avoid large monolithic builds where each team re-compiles the source code of another team's library.

When consuming C++ DLLs *with C++ interfaces* it is [rather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331045/using-c-dlls-with-different-compiler-versions) [clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233118/library-abi-compatibility-between-versions-of-visual-studio) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232926/how-to-make-consistent-dll-binaries-across-vs-versions) you only can do this if all DLLs are compiled with the same compiler / Visual Studio version.

What is not readily apparent to me is *what*, exactly needs to be the same to get ABI compatibility.

- *Obviously* debug (`_DEBUG`) and release (`NDEBUG`) cannot be mixed -- but that's also apparent from the fact that these link to different versions of the shared runtime.
- Do you need the exact same *compiler* version, or is it sufficient that the resulting DLL links to the same *shared* C++ runtime -- that is, basically to the same [redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)? (I think static doesn't fly when passing full C++ objects around)
- Is there a documented list of [compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx?) (and linker) options that need to be the same for two C++ DLLs of the same vc++ version to be compatible?

  - For example, is the same `/O` switch necessary - does the optimization level affect ABI compatibility´? (I'm pretty sure not.)
  - Or do both version have to use the same [`/EH` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx?)?
  - Or [`/volatile:ms|iso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx?) ... ?

**Essentially, I'd like to come up with a set of (meta-)data to associate with a Visual-C++ DLL that describes it's ABI compatibility.**

If differences exist, my focus is on VS2015 only at the moment.

Comment: In general, you should try to ensure the same version of CRT for all binaries.  It might work otherwise, but not guaranteed.  I can't answer to the C++ compiler settings, but it is a best practice to standardize all compiler / linker settings across your teams.

Comment: `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is [also a thing that must be equal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15951016/321013) , since it influences the std-lib object layout.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md

Answer (score 3):

Have been thinking this through the last days, and what I did do was to try to see if some use-cases exists where devs have already needed to categorize their C++ build to make sure binaries are compatible.

One such place is the [Native Packages from nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/native-packages). So I looked at one package there, specifically the [cpprestsdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/):

The binaries in the [downloadable package](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn/2.8.0) as split like this:

```
native\v120\windesktop\msvcstl\dyn\rt-dyn\x64\Release\
        ^      ^         ^      ^    ^     
  VS version   |       not sure |    uses cpp-runtime dynamically
               |               lib itself dynamic (as opposed to static)
    or WinXP or WinApp(WinRT?)
```

I pulled this out from this example, because I couldn't find any other docs. I also know that the boost binaries build directory is separated in a similar way.

So, to get to a list of meta data to identify the ABI compatibility, I can preliminarily list the following:

- VC version (that is, the version of the C and CPP runtime libraries used)

  - one point here is that e.g. `vc140` should be enough nowadays - given how the CRT is linked in, all possible bugfixes to the versioned CRT components must be ABI compatible anyway, so it shouldn't matter which version a given precompiled library was built with.
- pure native | managed (/CLI) | WinRT
- how the CRT is consumed (statically / dynamically)
- bitness / platform (Win32, x64, ARM, etc.)
- Release or Debug version (i.e. which version of the CRT we link to)
- plus: `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` ... if everyone goes with the defaults, fine, if a project does not, it must declare so

Additionally my *best guess* as to the following items:

- `/O` must not matter - we constantly mix&match binaries with different optimization settings - specifically, this is even working for object files within the same binary
- `/volatile` - since this is a code-gen thing, I have a hard time imagining how this could break an ABI
- `/EH` - except for the option to disable all exception, in which case you obviously can't call anything that throws, I'm pretty confident this is save from an ABI perspective: There are possible pitfalls here, but I think they can't really be categorized into ABI compat. (Maybe some complex callback chains could be said to be ABI incompatible, not sure)

Others:

- Default calling convention (`/G..`) : I *think* this would break at link time, when mangled export symbols and header declarations don't match up.
- `/Zc:wchar_t` - will break at link time (It's actually ABI compatible, but the symbols won't macth.)
- Enable RTTI (`/GR`) - not too sure 'bout this one - I never have worked with this disabled.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I wonder if "Character Set" also is an issue; Unicode vs MBCS vs ASCII?

Comment: @dicksters - I'm pretty sure UNICODE vs MBCS does not matter, because all these settings macros do is compile in different APIs, e.g. FoobarA() vs FoobarW() etc.